# bar appear next to navigation item

Tags: ios, swift

A bar appear next to my navigation item, my item is an image and I don't understand why a bar appear and I found that the bar appear only in device with iOS 9,10 devices with iOS 11 works perfectly.

[image]

If someone have an idea.

Here a screenshot of main storyboard
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUmLe.png)

and here one with all my item
[item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHNFG.png)

Comment: Can u show us the screenshot of your storyboard

Comment: I edit my post with a screenshot

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. when I said that I meant for you to include a picture of the Views Hieracrchy (the view of what objects are inside other objects)

Comment: No matter, now you have everything I hope.